# Trouble with a switch statement in a lexical analyzer

Tags: c, switch-statement, lexical-analysis

I am trying to make a lexical analyzer in C, and I have tried going through the code step by step to see where the issue is but I can't see it. This code reads a line from a file, assuming the first line and nothing else is in the file. So I tested it with `"a = (b + 2) * c"`.

It works, and prints out `a`, `=` but then nothing. I figured its a problem with the `switch` statement in my `lookup()` function because it seems to be working fine with anything not `UNKNOWN` in `lex()`. Any insight would be helpful and appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int charClass;
char lexeme[100];
char nextChar;
int lexLen;
int token;
int nextToken;
FILE *fp;

void addChar();
void getChar();
void getNonBlank();
int lex();

#define LETTER 0
#define DIGIT 1
#define UNKNOWN 99

#define INT_LIT 10
#define IDENT 11
#define ASSIGN_OP 20
#define ADD_OP 21
#define SUB_OP 22
#define MULT_OP 23
#define DIV_OP 24
#define LEFT_PARENT 25
#define RIGHT_PARENT 26

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fopen == NULL)
        printf("File can not be opened");
    else {
        getChar();

        while (nextToken != EOF) {
            lex();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int lookup(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
    case '(':
        addChar();
        nextToken = LEFT_PARENT;
        break;
    case ')':
        addChar();
        nextToken = RIGHT_PARENT;
        break;
    case '+':
        addChar();
        nextToken = ADD_OP;
        break;
    case '-':
       addChar();
        nextToken = SUB_OP;
        break;
    case '*':
        addChar();
        nextToken = MULT_OP;
        break;
    case '/':
        addChar();
        nextToken = DIV_OP;
        break;
    default:
        addChar();
        nextToken = EOF;
    }
    return nextToken;
}

void addChar() {
    if (lexLen <= 98) {
        lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;
        lexeme[lexLen] = 0;
    } else
        printf("Error- lexele is too long...\n");
}

void getChar() {
    if ((nextChar = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(nextChar))
            charClass = LETTER;
        else if(isdigit(nextChar))
             charClass = DIGIT;
        else
            charClass = UNKNOWN;
    } else
        charClass =EOF;
}

void getNonBlank() {
    while (isspace(nextChar))
        getChar();
}

int lex() {
    lexLen = 0;
    getNonBlank();
    switch (charClass) {
    case LETTER:
        addChar();
        getChar();
        while (charClass == LETTER || charClass == DIGIT) {
            addChar();
            getChar();
        }
        nextToken = IDENT;
        break;
    case DIGIT:
        addChar();
        getChar();
        while (charClass == DIGIT) {
            addChar();
            getChar();
        }
        nextToken = INT_LIT;
        break;
    case UNKNOWN:
        lookup(nextChar);
        getChar();
        break;
    case EOF:
        nextToken = EOF;
        lexeme[0] = 'E';
        lexeme[1] = 'O';
        lexeme[2] = 'F';
        lexeme[3] = 0;
    }
    printf("Next token is :%d, next lexeme is %s\n", nextToken, lexeme);
    return nextToken;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Few changes and it is possible to read `a = (b + 2) * c`, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first remark, when you get a char and want to compare it with EOF you have to save the char in an *int*, not in a char, so

```
void getChar()
{
    if((nextChar=getc(fp))!=EOF)
        {
        if(isalpha(nextChar))
            charClass=LETTER;
            else if(isdigit(nextChar))
                charClass=DIGIT;
        else
            charClass=UNKNOWN;
        }   
    else
        charClass=EOF;
}
```

do not well manages the *EOF* case because *nextChar* is a *char*, can be :

```
void getChar()
{
    if((charClass=getc(fp))!=EOF)
        {
      nextChar = charClass;
        if(isalpha(nextChar))
            charClass=LETTER;
            else if(isdigit(nextChar))
                charClass=DIGIT;
        else
            charClass=UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

A second remark is you forget to manage the case '=', so I think in `lookup(char ch)` you have to add the case :

```
case '=':addChar();
       nextToken=ASSIGN_OP;
  break;
```

this is why you stop after you read '='.

If I do these changes :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wextra q.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat in
a = (b + 2) * c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out in
Next token is :11, next lexeme is a
Next token is :20, next lexeme is =
Next token is :25, next lexeme is (
Next token is :11, next lexeme is b
Next token is :21, next lexeme is +
Next token is :10, next lexeme is 2
Next token is :26, next lexeme is )
Next token is :23, next lexeme is *
Next token is :11, next lexeme is c
^C
```

I have to kill the execution because the program loops, this is because in `getNonBlank()` the *EOF* case is not managed, so :

```
void getNonBlank()
{
    while((charClass != EOF) && isspace(nextChar))
        getChar();
}
```

After that change :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out in
Next token is :11, next lexeme is a
Next token is :20, next lexeme is =
Next token is :25, next lexeme is (
Next token is :11, next lexeme is b
Next token is :21, next lexeme is +
Next token is :10, next lexeme is 2
Next token is :26, next lexeme is )
Next token is :23, next lexeme is *
Next token is :11, next lexeme is c
Next token is :-1, next lexeme is EOF
```

---

As chqrlie says in a remark also replace `if(fopen == NULL)` by `if (fp == NULL)`

Comment: Thank you! I completely overlooked i didn't even have the case in there because it printed the '=' and i thought the issue was the parenthesis. I'll also keep in mind the other remarks too, I appreciate the feedback!